# how to sort a list of object value in an object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

This is the query that i use to fetch items and item detail of each item with specific id

```
public class ItemModel 
{
   public int ItemSeq{get;set}
   public string ItemName{get;set;}
   public double? Amount{get;set;}
}
public class SampleModel
{
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string Code{ get; set; }
    public List<ItemModel> Items{ get; set; }
}

public List<SampleModel> GetItems(string id)
{

    var items= _context.ItemTable.Where(t => t.Id== id).ToList<SampleModel>();
    return list;
}
```

To make the requirement clear there are two table `ItemTable` and `ItemDetailTable` And `Id` being `ItemTable` primary key and foreign key in `ItamDetailTable`and the `ItemDetailTable` may have multiple values for a single `ID` and the above query returns the item and the details from `ItemDetailTable` with the specific id what i want is to have a sorted item detail value by the value of `Amount`. Is there any way to do that ?

Sample Data

ItemTable

```
Id     Code
1      Code1
2      Code3
```

ItemDetailTable

```
Id    ItemSeq    ItemName    Amount
1     1          ABC1        200
1     2          ABC2        129
1     3          ABC3        549
2     1          DEF1        265
2     2          DEf2        970
```

what i want is when the value of `Id` is 1 the return value to be

```
Id:   1
Code: Code 1
Items:[
    0:{
     ItemSeq:  2
     ItemName: ABC2
     Amount:   129
    }
   1:{
     ItemSeq:  1
     ItemName: ABC1
     Amount:   200
    },
   1:{
     ItemSeq:  3
     ItemName: ABC3
     Amount:   549
    }
]
```

Comment: What is _"item details"_ here?

Comment: by the value of Amount Which is in `ItemModel` `public double? Amount{get;set;}`

Comment: Amount is a property of a nested collection in SampleModel. Do you want to order the SampleModel by the max Amount in their nested collections? By the sum? Please show some example data and desired output Also please show what you have tried already

Comment: @hana_wujira, after you last edit whats the role of `ItemModel` and `SampleModel` in your question. plz edit to question?

Comment: @GiladGreen Green  i have updated the question

Comment: @hana_wujira, I added my answer below might be it help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return sorted list of `ItemModel` by passing `id` parameter to  `GetItems` method.

```
public List<ItemModel> GetItems(string id)
{
    var items = _context.SampleTable.Where(t => t.Id == id).SelectMany(x => x.Items).Where(p => p.Amount != null).OrderBy(x => x.Amount).ToList();
    return items.ToList();
}
```

**Edit:**

> the above query returns the item and the details from ItemDetailTable with the specific id

You also need to add foreign key property to ItemDetailTable like

```
public class ItemDetailTable
{
    public int ItemSeq { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public double? Amount { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }   //Foreign key of ItemTable
}


public ItemTable GetItems(string id)
{
    //Get "ItemTable" record from database
    var item = _context.ItemTable.Where(x => x.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();

    //Retrieve its "Items" and sort by ascending order
    var itemDetails = item.Items.Where(x => x.Id == id).Where(p => p.Amount != null).OrderBy(x => x.Amount).ToList();

    //Preare a new "ItemTable" object to return
    ItemTable itemTable = new ItemTable
    {
        Code = item.Code,
        Id = item.Id,
        Items = itemDetails
    };

    //Return new "itemTable" with sorted list of "ItemDetailTable"
    return itemTable;
}
```

**Edit 2:**

```
public ItemTable GetItems(string id)
{
    var result = (from i in _context.ItemTable
                  where i.Id == id
                  let sorting = i.Items.Where(x => x.Id == id).Where(x => x.Amount != null).OrderBy(x => x.Amount).ToList()
                  select new ItemTable
                  {
                      Id = i.Id,
                      Code = i.Code,
                      Items = sorting
                  }).FirstOrDefault();   //Or => SingleOrDefault

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works.  but i was wondering if there is any other way which doesn't involve making two queries and merging the values ?

Comment: view **Edit 2:** section in answer :)